# Ubuntu 12.10 No USB sound output for Audiolab Q-DAC

Tags: 12.10, sound, usb, pulseaudio

Recently I upgraded my sound system from using mobo's internal audio output to USB2.0 by connecting to a USB DAC (Audiolab Q-DAC). The first time connecting the UBUNTU 12.10 to USB DAC was successful, but after a system upgrade (apt-get update & upgrade). No sound output at all. I can still choose the USB Stereo output option in Pulseaudio control panel, but no sound output. It seems that the connection has been automatically muted. How can I un-mute it? Same problem exists even though I upgraded to 13.04.

I have dumped the output of the command `lspci` as follows:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/Ivy Bridge DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579V Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 8 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Z77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
04:00.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8606 6 Lane, 6 Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ba)
05:01.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8606 6 Lane, 6 Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ba)
05:04.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8606 6 Lane, 6 Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ba)
05:05.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8606 6 Lane, 6 Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ba)
05:07.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8606 6 Lane, 6 Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ba)
05:09.0 PCI bridge: PLX Technology, Inc. PEX 8606 6 Lane, 6 Port PCI Express Gen 2 (5.0 GT/s) Switch (rev ba)
07:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9172 SATA 6Gb/s Controller (rev 11)
0a:00.0 PCI bridge: Integrated Technology Express, Inc. Device 8892 (rev 30)
0b:02.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB22A IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link) [iOHCI-Lynx]
0c:00.0 SATA controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88SE9172 SATA 6Gb/s Controller (rev 11)
```

This output dump seems there's no connection with the USB DAC even though I had connected the USB device before the dumping of lspci. Why?

Regards,
Gordon

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after a system upgrade.
The solution for me was to set the profile for the dac to analog stereo output.
This can be done in the tab Configuration of the program PulseAudio volume control.